# Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct in my code

Tags: c#, asp.net, inner-classes

I am studying the NerdDinner tutorial. And I get an error in my code. I think I mess up with inner class and the number of bracks. But I really dont have any idea on how to figure it out. Anyone can help me? Thanks. Below is my code:

```
namespace NerdDinner.Models
{
    public partial class DinnerViolation
    {
        public bool isValid
        {
            get { return (GetRuleViolations().Count() == 0); }
        }

        public IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations()
        {
            yield break;
        }

        public void OnValidate(ChangeAction action)
        {
            if (!isValid)
                throw new ApplicationException("Rule violations prevent saving");
        }
    }

        public class RuleViolation
        {
            public string ErrorMessage { get; private set; }
            public string PropertyName { get; private set; }

            public RuleViolation(string errormessage, string propertyName)
            {
                ErrorMessage = errormessage;
                PropertyName = propertyName;
            }
        }

            public IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations()//Error appears here
            {

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Title))
                    yield return new RuleViolation("Title required", "Title");

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Description))
                    yield return new RuleViolation("Description required", "Description");

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(HostedBy))
                    yield return new RuleViolation("HostedBy", "HostedBy");

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Address))
                    yield return new RuleViolation("Address required", "Address");

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Country))
                    yield return new RuleViolation("Country required", "Country");

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContactPhone))
                    yield return new RuleViolation("ContactPhone required", "ContactPhone");

                if (!PhoneValidator.IsValidNumber(ContactPhone, Country))
                    yield return new RuleViolation("Phone# does not match country", "ContactPhone");

                yield break;
            }

        public class PhoneValidator
        {
            static IDictionary<string, Regex> countryRegex = new Dictionary<string, Regex>() {           
            { "USA", new Regex("^[2-9]\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$")},            
            { "UK", new Regex("(^1300\\d{6}$)|(^1800|1900|1902\\d{6}$)|(^0[2|3|7|8]{1}[0-9]{8}$)|(^13\\d{4}$)|(^04\\d{2,3}\\d{6}$)")},            
            { "Netherlands", new Regex("(^\\+[0-9]{2}|^\\+[0-9]{2}\\(0\\)|^\\(\\+[0-9]{2}\\)\\(0\\)|^00[0-9]{2}|^0)([0-9]{9}$|[0-9\\-\\s]{10}$)")},    
            };

            public static bool IsValidNumber(string phoneNumber, string country)
            {
                if (country != null && countryRegex.ContainsKey(country))
                    return countryRegex[country].IsMatch(phoneNumber);
                else
                    return false;
            }

            public static IEnumerable<string> Countries
            {
                get
                {
                    return countryRegex.Keys;
                }
            }

        }
 }
```

Comment: Your method `GetRuleViolations()` is not inside of a class. And as it is, it can't really be placed in any class, because it makes references that don't exist (`Title`, `Description`...)

Comment: `public IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations()` is not inside any of your classes. Move it into a class or create one for it.

Answer (score 3):

This declaration is the problem:

```
public IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations()
```

This method doesn't exist in a class. Which class did you *think* it was in? Whichever class you want it to be in, move it there.

A few points to note:

- If you ask Visual Studio to indent your code, you'll get a much better idea of what's going on. For example, you've indented `RuleViolation` further than `DinnerViolation` for no particular reason.
- I wouldn't use nested classes unless you've actually got a good reason to. Top-level classes are easier to reason about.
- If you keep one class per source file, it's harder to get confused about scope and what's where.